# Unity Unet error "Cannot open socket on ip{*},and port{7777}"

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

Was trying out new unity networking on unity version 5.3.0f4 looking at the docs , all was working well but today when I host a game on localhost using one pc build and the other on the editor running on the same pc , I get this error after joining the either two one after the another .My firewall is off , and no other software open.[image]

Comment: Did you check if the port is occupied?

Comment: well I did change to other ports using network manager component but using netstat -a I cannot see 7777 anywhere but i can see the port 8080 witha *::* sign neither listening or broadcasting

Comment: @GeraldSchneider using netstat -an i see this  UDP    [::]:7777      *:*

Comment: strange its working now , did not change a thing !

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out , silly mistake if another instance of the game is running and you hosted the game through it , and you forget to close it , the editor will give the above error if you try to host a game before closing the other instance of the game.

Comment: I made a StopHost() call right before the StartHost() call and it seemed to fix it for now.